# Raphael conflict to MDL

Tags: javascript, html, raphael, material-design-lite

Raphael JS looks like conflict to my Material Design Lite. When I use Raphael, I see this MDL error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid argument provided to upgrade MDL element.
at a (material.min.js:8)
at n (material.min.js:8)
at Object._ [as upgradeAllRegistered] (material.min.js:8)
at material.min.js:8
```

and can't upgrade MDL element.

Comment: Welcome! Please also provide us the code that is causing this error. This will help others to give you a better answer. Thanks

Comment: If I added this code: `<script src="scripts/raphael.min.js"></script>`, will error.